# App freezes while looping through screen pixels

Tags: java, loops

My app freezes while executing this code in a timer which runs every 100ms:

```
Dimension screenRect = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Robot robot = null;
try {
    robot = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
}
for(int y = screenRect.height / 2 - 50; y < screenRect.height / 2 + 50; y++) {
    for(int x = screenRect.width / 2 - 50; x < screenRect.width / 2 + 50; x++) {
        Color c = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
        if(c.getRed() >= 170 && c.getGreen() >= 90 && c.getBlue() >= 80) {
             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
             robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        }
    }
}
```

It should press A if it finds the color in there. But it freezes and doesn't loop all through and stops working.

Comment: Double checking your math would be the first step in my opinion, make sure it's formatted properly within the loops.

Comment: @beefoak what do you mean? Math should be right.

Comment: try one thing, remove color and reboot code and print any variable in nested loops check. is loop able to complete ?
It will at least clear that your looping are right.

Comment: for(int y = screenRect.height / 2 - 50; y < screenRect.height / 2 + 50; y++) {
    for(int x = screenRect.width / 2 - 50; x < screenRect.width / 2 + 50; x++) {
     System.out.print("a ")
    }
}
Like this.